# how to get the value of different editText inside the hashmap in android

Tags: android, hashmap, android-edittext

Please help me fix this one. I'm already stock in this. I am trying to get the values of the editText inside the hashmap using the code below. It creates multiple editText depending upon the number of files that the user selected.

```
//SAVE All Attachment
EditText txt_iDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_iDesc);

SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();

for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
{
    String desc = txt_iDesc.getText().toString();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_REPORTCODE, ReportCode);
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILENAME, map.get(FILE_NAME));
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DESCRIPTION, desc);
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILELOCATION, map.get(FILE_URI));
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_CREATEDBY, map.get(UPLOADED_BY));
    cv.put(Constants.ATTACH_DATECREATED, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));

    db.insert(Constants.TABLE_ATTACH, null, cv);
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

[image]

But when I save it. It only gets the value of the first editText. When I retrieved the data that has been saved it shows that the value "one" of the first editText was the only saved, thats my problem, I don't know what to do save the value of different editText inside the hasmap.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ummm...you only show one `EditText`. Where are the others in your code?

Anyway, you say, "It creates multiple editText depending upon the number of files that the user selected." Then when you create each `EditText` put them in an `Array` then you can iterate through them to get the text of each to put in the `HashMap`

Comment: that was only the editText i used in my adapter. I was thinking if i need to do a loop or what. @codeMagic can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txt_iDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_iDesc);

for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist)
{
// you are using the same edit text reference in your code, you should create multiple edit  text
 String desc = txt_iDesc.getText().toString();
//...
 }
```